# beside herself with worry for

Tags: phrase-usage

1. Mona was driving toward the hospital, beside herself with worry for her husband.
2. Mona was driving toward the hospital, out of herself with worry for her husband.

- Is the phrase "beside oneself with" used naturally here?
- Is the second sentence also possible (to mean the same)?

Comment: Idiomatic ***to be beside oneself*** (out of one's wits, out of one's senses, usually because ***very angry***) was first recorded in 1490. But for centuries it's been a fixed ***set phrase*** that's not "linguistically productive" (it hasn't led to any *new* usages). You can say someone is  ***out of their mind***, or ***scared out of their wits***, but we don't normally say someone is ***out of themselves***. And if someone *did* say ***I was out of myself*** I'd probably interpret that as meaning "spaced out" or "daydreaming" rather than "angry" anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> Mona was driving toward the hospital, beside herself with worry for her husband.

Sounds totally natural and correct.  Here is the [definition from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/beside%20oneself) in case it helps.

> Mona was driving toward the hospital, out of herself with worry for her husband.

This one I haven't heard before.  Maybe you meant "[out of her mind with worry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out%20of%20one%27s%20mind%20with%20worry)"? I searched for this to see if it is common or if I could find a definition, no luck.  The most similar phrase I could find means something entirely different ([to talk oneself out of something](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/talk%20%28oneself%29%20out%20of%20%28something%29) OR [to take you out of yourself](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-take-you-out-of-yourself)).

I took a look at [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=out+of+herself+with%2Cbeside+herself+with%2Coutside+herself+with%2C+out+of+her+mind+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20herself%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeside%20herself%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coutside%20herself%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20her%20mind%20with%3B%2Cc0) and it seems to confirm that "beside herself with" is more typical than "out of herself with".